# why i am getting only rating of one business?

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, numeric, rating

```
<?php
$business=$model->reviewBusinesses;
foreach ($business as $business) {
    $c = $business->rating; ?>
    <div class="ratings"> <!--use class in order to show rating horizontally -->
    <?php 
    $this->widget('ext.DzRaty.DzRaty', array(
        'name' => 'rating',
        'value' => $c,
        'options' => array(
            'readOnly' => TRUE,
        ),
    ));
    ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am working in `yii` and using dzraty extension for star rating. In one of my view file which is `userbusiness.php` of `business` table which has relationship with `revewbusiness` table. I am getting rating from `reviewbusiness` table and showing it in one of my view file of `business` as mentioned above. I am getting rating in numeric form, but from above code i can only get `rating` of 1st review in star form while the rest of the rating is coming in numeric form. Can someone find my error?
like this

```
first_star second_star third_star fourth_star fifth_star
2
3
4
5
```

For those who really want to understand, in `reviewbusiness` table, i am getting rating, reviews of users.

Comment: You're clobbering `$business` in the the first iteration of the `foreach`. After the first iteration, your array is gone. Instead do: `foreach ($business as $biz)` and change the reference in the loop to `$biz`

Comment: you are refusing your variable inside loop

Comment: @Jonathan at the end i just now echo $c it is equals to 0. donot know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you are using `business` as data set and as key at the same time):

```
<?php $business = $model->reviewBusinesses;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($business as $business_key) {
        $c = $business_key->rating;
        ?>
        <div class="ratings"> <!--use class in order to show rating horizontally -->
        <?php 
        $this->widget('ext.DzRaty.DzRaty', array( 
        'name' => 'rating_'.$i,
        'value' => $c,
        'options' => array(
            'readOnly' => TRUE,
            ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'id' => 'rating_'.$i,
        ),
        )); ?>
        </div>
      <?php 
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I added a $i counter at each business name attribute so this will be different for each one.

Comment: Oh jesus, @kostas, it worked but only one problem, i am getting 0 rating in first iteration.

Comment: Check if that rating is 0. Echo $c for each business in loop.

Comment: oh yea :D thanks thanks a lot it was coming from database. @kostas thanks so much it worked. God bless you :)

Comment: Nice! I' m glad that i helped you.